# Getting Respond Time from Ping Command

Tags: batch-file, ping

I'm trying to create a batch file that will ping a certain server and will only display the respond time. I don't mind if value is stored in a variable or not.

If you do a normal ping you get:

```
Reply from <hostname/server>: bytes=#byte_value time=#time_value TTL=#TTL_value
```

And I only want:

```
#time_value
```

I don't know if i need to use particular `tokens` or use `findstr` for the time value. I have failed every attempts so far.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From command line:

```
==>ping -4 -n 1 google.com|findstr /i "TTL="
Reply from 173.194.112.105: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=56

==>for /F "tokens=7 delims== " %G in ('ping -4 -n 1 google.com^|findstr /i "TTL="') do @echo %G
17ms

==>
```

Used in a batch:

```
for /F "tokens=7 delims== " %%G in ('
    ping -4 -n 1 google.com^|findstr /i "TTL="') do @echo %%G
```

Read entire `for /?` or [`FOR /F` Loop command: against the results of another command](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html).